# Moodle - use plugin/db/install.xml or plugin/db/install.php when creating a new plugin?

Tags: sql, database, moodle

Is there any reason for which I should prefer one of the means of creating new database tables for a plugin over the other? It seems like most of the core plugins use an XML file but I know that I can also use the $DB->get_manager() to create tables, as in an upgrade script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both used but for different reasons.

install.xml is used to create any database tables that you need. You should use the xmldb editor to create the file. As well as creating the file, it will also check for any restricted column and table names - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_editor

install.php is executed straight after install.xml and is used when you want to set up any data or settings that you need. For example if you create a lookup table in install.xml, then use install.php to populate the table.

You should also use install.php if you want to make any changes to the core tables.

Note though that install.xml and install.php are only called once. So if the plugin is already installed, then you will need to use upgrade.php to make any changes.

You should keep install.xml and install.php up to date though in case you want to install the plugin elsewhere.